# JavaScript assignment with operation *= conundrum

Tags: javascript

Following code is giving me a big time headache

```
        var somearr = [1, 2, 3];

        function operations() {
             for (var i = 0; i < somearr.length;) {
                   //alert (somearr[i++] *= 2); // statement-1

                    alert(somearr[i++] = somearr[i++] * 2); //statement-2

        }

   }

  operations();
```

Conceptually statement-1 and statement-2 are same (see the comments in the code above). I know that  **somearr[i++]** is evaluated once in statement-1 and twice in statement-2. However what I don't understand is that output of statement-1 (after recursive iteration) is **[2,4,6]** which is expected but the output of the  recursively executing statement-2 is **[4,NaN]** (totally confused with this output).

On top of that when I try to debug this code using Visual Studio and put a break point in front of statement-2 when the break point is hit I just stay at the statement-2 (forever) without debugging the code any further and noticed (nearly after every 10 to 15 seconds) that index value i++ automatically gets incremented without even debugging the code further (as I said earlier) , I'm kinda totally stumped that how come visual studio debugger auto increments index i value without letting me debug the code (that is, recursively iterating all the index values) and stops increment once the value if i++ = 3.

Comment: Consider that `somearr[3]` is `undefined` and `undefined * 2` is `NaN`.

Comment: First iteration is doing `somearr[0] = somearr[1] * 2;` (4), second iteration is doing `somearr[2] = somearr[3] * 2;` (`somearr[3]` is undefined, `NaN`: Not a Number). Learn about the JavaScript console, it's a handy tool you should always use before asking a question.

Comment: @Blex you are absolutely right but what I can't understand that how come rigth side of the statement somearr[0] = somearr[1] * 2; gets index as 1, since it's my very first iteration it should be 0.

Comment: You're doing `i++` on the left hand side of `=`. So `i` is now equal to `1`. And so forth.

Comment: Each use of `i++` alters `i` immediately, so the variable's value changes between the 2 uses in statement-2. Breaking up the statement a bit, you can get a some more insight: `var _a = i++, _b = i++; somearr[_a] = somearr[_b] * 2; console.log(_a, _b);` -- http://jsfiddle.net/28d70opv/

Comment: but i ++ will increment i's value once i++ is executed and resulting value of i++ is assigned again to variable i , which is not happening once I just hit the statement somearr[0] = somearr[1] * 2;  for the very first time.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I got you sir, any comment on the second confusion that how come JavaScript runtime is auto incrementing index i value without me further debugging the code any more.

Comment: @user2913184 It isn't auto-incrementing, if by that you mean changing the value of `i` for you. The `++` is what's doing that. If you didn't include those operators, `i` would always remain at `0` and the loop would continue infinitely (at least, until the browser acknowledges the page isn't responding and asks if you want to stop it or let it continue). Debuggers typically allow stepping through code statement-by-statement. Since both increments are contained in the same statement, they'll be evaluated together as you step through it.

Comment: Yeah both increments happen when I step through, but that's what I'm confused about, that even when I don't step through and hit the break point the very first time and stay there value of i keeps on incrementing until it becomes 3.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you're incrementing i twice in statement 2.  So multiplying by null (which is what you get when you pull an index not in your array) returns NaN.

It is best practice to increment inside your for-loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < somearr.length; i++) {
  //somearr[i] *= 2; // statement-1

  //somearr[i] = somearr[i] * 2; //statement-2
}
```

Now both statements work.

your code was as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < somearr.length;) {
    somearr[i++] = somearr[i++] * 2;
}
```

At execution we evaluate somearr[i++]:
i = 0, somearr[0] = 1 
We set this to equal to somearr[1] * 2 (somearr[1] since we incremented after our first evaluation).
Therefore the first index of somearr becomes 4, and i is currently set to 2, since we incremented again.

Now we check somearr[2], which gives us 3.  We set this value to equal somearr[3] * 2.  But somearr[3] is null, because we are now past the array's indices.  This evaluates to NaN because 2*null is NaN.

our i is now 4, because we incremented again, and our array is [4, NaN].  We stop looping because i = 4, which terminates the for-loop

Comment: yes you are right but what I don't understand is that how come somearr[0] = somearr[1] * 2; this code gets index value as 1 on the right side of the assignment where as for the very first iteration value of I should be 0.

Comment: @user2913184 - after the first `somearr[i++]` is executed, then `i === 1` for the next part of the statement.  Each invocation of `i++` makes the value of `i` go up right after that term.

Comment: Give me a minute and I'll update my answer with an at-runtime analysis of your code.

Comment: Thanks sir ChadF, i hope u can reproduce what is happening on my machine.

Comment: @user2913184: JavaScript always evaluates the values of variables from left to right as the expression is executed. That's why the value of `i` changes in the middle of that expression statement. It gets the value of `i`, then increments it, then gets the value of `i` again.

Answer (score 1):

> the output of statement-1 is `[2,4,6]` which is expected

Yes. If we unroll the loop, we get

```
var somearr = [1, 2, 3];
somearr[0] *= 2; // somearr[0] = somearr[0] * 2;
somearr[1] *= 2; // somearr[1] = somearr[1] * 2;
somearr[2] *= 2; // somearr[2] = somearr[2] * 2;
// i (3) is no more smaller than somearr.length (3) after the third iteration
```

> the output of executing statement-2 is `[4,NaN]` (totally confused with this output).

Actually the output of `somearr` is `[4, 2, NaN]`. Why is that? Because `i++` is evaluated twice per body execution. The loop now unrolls to

```
var somearr = [1, 2, 3];
somearr[0] = somearr[1] * 2; // 2 * 2
somearr[2] = somearr[3] * 2; // undefined * 2
// i (4) is no more smaller than somearr.length (3) after the second iteration
```

Comment: It's [4,NaN] not [4,2,NaN], Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please include the code you use for "output" in your question. The `somearr` is definitely `[4,2,NaN]` after the `operation()`, you haven't changed the array length.

Comment: Ok did it, it's just an alert function that I call.

Comment: Ah I guessed that, you're alerting each result of the assignments. The array notation you used for that is confusing. But yes, there are only two assignments taking place with the statement-2.

Comment: Still confused about my second question, well Jonathan replied back on that as well but I'm not fully convinced with what he said.

Comment: @user2913184: I don't know anything about the Visual Studio Debugger, sorry. But I can see that postfix increment operators are not trivial to represent with breakpoints.